# Generate series of incremented numbers from a mutually shared base

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, cursor, increment

I have a table called `SharedNumber`, which has only one field - an integer number called `LastNumber` which can have one and only one entry.

There are about 40 or 50 odd completely separate Access databases that use this `LastNumber` entry as a common reference point. It is essentially being used to manually generate unique primary keys for a system that isn't able to generate them by itself. It is ugly and messy, and I am in the process of gradually weaning them off one by one, but in the interim I need to build a process in SQL Server which would reference this same entry.

I am dealing with the following:

**1.**

The shared number table:

```
create table SharedNumber
( 
    [LastNumber] int not null
) ON [PRIMARY]


Insert into SharedNumber
values
(234) --This is the most recent shared number
```

**2.**

An input data table (`InputTable`) that will continuously receive new entries, and for which new `ContractID` fields values need to be generated manually by incrementing `LastNumber`. For simplicty, let's say this table is uniquely defined on `Name`.

```
create table InputTable
(

    [ContractID] int NULL,
    [Name] varchar(50) not null
 ) ON [PRIMARY]


Insert into InputTable
values
(101,'ABC'),
(102,'DEF'),
(NULL,'GHI'),
(NULL,'JKL'),
(NULL,'MNO')
```

Entries 'GHI', 'JKL' and 'MNO' need `ContractID` values, so I want to incrementally create new numbers for them, based on `LastNumber`, and then update `LastNumber` to the last one that was generated. The eventual result I want is:

```
ContractID    Name
101           ABC
102           DEF
235           GHI
236           JKL
237           MNO


LastNumber
237
```

Anyone have any ideas on a good way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to do this directly in the DDL for the contract table.  This uses two columns and a computed column:

```
create table whatever (
    BuiltInContractId int identity(1000000,1) not null, -- the 1000000 is just to set a range for contract ids
    OverrideContractId int, -- what a user inputs,
    ContractId as coalesce(OverrideContractId, BuiltInContractId),
    . . .
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an instead-of trigger on insert.

Or even better: Solve the problem in the application logic in a central place.